# What and how much domain code should be put in an F# module

Tags: domain-driven-design, code-organization, f#

According to recommendations given [here](https://vimeo.com/97507575#t=25m0s), F# modules should correspond to DDD bounded contexts, i.e. subdivisions of a business domain.

The bounded context I'm working on right now has 2 aggregates totalling a dozen of types, plus some rather complex functions/algorithms. If I follow the prescribed style, I end up with a 500+ LOC file, which IMO isn't very readable or navigatable, and it will only grow longer. Unfortunately, it seems F# modules [can't be split across multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793536/split-f-modules-across-multiple-files).

Other solutions I've attempted are :

- One module per aggregate. Problem -- if I include the aggregate type in the module, I end up with an inelegant aggregate type name (e.g. `MyAggregate.MyAggregate`), especially when reused in non-F# .NET code.
- One file with all the types of the bounded context under a particular *namespace* and another file containing the functions inside a module. Still not satisfying since in F# I can't give the same name to the module and namespace, and functions are not really organized inside the file.

  ```
  // This gives a "namespace and module named ... both occur in 2 parts of this assembly" error

  //File1.fs

  namespace MyProject.Domain.MyBC

  type MyType = 
      // ...

  //File2.fs

  namespace MyProject.Domain

  module MyBC = //...
  ```

I'm still looking for a solution that satisfies the following

- Meaningful organization of code reflecting DDD concepts, so that code lookup feels easy and obvious
- Some degree of compartmentalization, to prevent native access to other unrelated parts of the domain and avoid mistakes
- Low cognitive load to explore a file (meaning no more than a few hundred lines of code per file)
- Simple, non contrived usage from external non-F# .NET code

Have I missed the obvious way of doing it, or does the lack of partial modules + namespace/module collision just make them an awkward scope for DDD?

Comment: Perhaps, if that particular Bounded Context is so big, it would make sense to put it in a separate library..?

Comment: "Low cognitive load to explore a file" has absolutely no relation to the number of lines of code in a file. If you find it hard to read it's probably because you're intertwining pure code with side effects. About DDD first see http://stackoverflow.com/a/2181281/21239

Comment: @MauricioScheffer "has absolutely no relation to the number of lines" -- do you have any link to research or something to back up that claim ? I have a visual memory so the longer the file, the more time it takes to find what I need. Plus it's a pretty common recommendation to keep code files reasonably short. Better a series of small labeled bags than a giant rag bag.

Comment: @MarkSeemann I don't see a 2-aggregate BC as particularly big. Plus that would mean a separate library with a single file in it containing a single module ?

Comment: @guillaume31 Do you have a link to research to back up the opposite? :) I just say it from my own experience. If you keep your code as pure as possible you usually don't *need* to scan an entire file to understand the code. You can focus on particular functions as the scope is smaller, and then you navigate to other functions as needed.

Comment: @MauricioScheffer you're the one making the claim, not me :) If you know that there's a function that does X but can't remember where it is, are you more likely to find it quickly in a 1000 LOC file or in a 80 LOC file ?

Comment: @guillaume31 we are both making claims, just opposite. If you can't remember where a function is, you'd have to search for it across the whole project anyway... you can start searching by module name for example.

Comment: Any chance you could link to the part in the video with the module recommendation?  For example, if it was at 3:28, you could link to https://vimeo.com/97507575#t=3m28s

Comment: You can use the [<CompilationRepresentation(CompilationRepresentationFlags.ModuleSuffix)>] attribute on your module to deal with the module/type naming issue you mention.

Comment: @bentayloruk It's at https://vimeo.com/97507575#t=25m0s

Comment: @bentayloruk Thanks for the tip. I ended up using 1 module per aggregate as a least-worst solution. Amount of code per file is still a big blocker for me --and it's only been growing since I asked the question. I must be different than most functional programmers in that regard ;)

Comment: @guillaume31I'm sure you'll get to a happy place soon enough!  We can do better than "least-worst"!  Thanks for the direct video link.  I've posted an answer as a result.

Comment: @guillaume31, any chance you could post your code in Code Review or in a gist? I'd be happy to see if I could refactor it to your satisfaction!

Comment: @Grundoon I'm afraid I'm not allowed to show the code as it is. I'm not unhappy with the design I've got now, I was just hoping to find F# constructs that would match DDD delineations to facilitate the projection of a programmer's mental model of the domain onto the code and vice versa. I'm almost there with BC's as namespaces and Aggregates as modules. Thanks for offering though, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

Having watched the section of the video you refer to, I don't see where Scott says a Bounded Context *should* correspond to a module.  He just happens to chose a module to represent the Bounded Context *in his example*.  There is absolutely no reason that a Bounded Context must correspond to a module.

If you feel your Bounded Context does not map well to a module, you are free to split it in whatever way you want.  It can as many modules and types as you want, partitioned by namespace(s), assembly or whatever else floats your boat.  All that matters is that the principles of a Bounded Context that you desire, are achieved.

With regards to file size and navigation, you could try [Visual F# Power Tools Navigate To](http://fsprojects.github.io/VisualFSharpPowerTools/navigateto.html) feature.

Comment: Absolutely, that's what I ended up doing. There's a trend though to consider Module = BC as a hard and fast rule -- I've heard it in other presentations and in conversations. Mark who commented on the question [tweeted about it](https://twitter.com/ploeh/status/530323467254894592). Besides, I can understand why people take it at face value, because there's hardly a middle ground in this. It doesn't make much sense to say "a module is kind of a BC but you have to look at other modules to have a view of the complete BC". Better to have no rule at all then.

Comment: I somehow feel that this could all be solved if we had partial modules as there are partial classes in C#. I haven't really had the time to look into why this isn't possible in F# though, so it might not be a good idea.

Comment: I don't see it myself.  A Bounded Context is a modelling concept.  There should not be any "hard and fast" rules about how it is represented in a specific language (IMO).  Will ping Mark and Scott to see if they can clarify.

Comment: I'm with @bentayloruk. The only hard and fast rule I follow is "there are no hard and fast rules". But what it's worth, here is what I do. First I generally keep function implementations away from the design, in a different module. That keeps the design part as small as possible and encourages abstraction. Note that I will often define function types in the design module as well if they are important part of the domain.

Comment: Second, as many others have suggested, if the design is getting too big, that's a clue that you might need to break it down into smaller sub-designs  or sub-modules.  In order to avoid issues with file order, and to encourage abstraction again, I might use generics (parametric polymorphism) to protect the upper layers from knowing anything about the specifics of the lower layers (see http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/removing-cyclic-dependencies/). That trick means that the high-level design can come first in file-order.

Comment: P.S. Eric Evans' latest thinking is that bounded contexts should be implemented as microservices (http://www.infoq.com/news/2015/06/dddx-microservices-boundaries) so just think of a module as a microservice and you should be fine!

Comment: Good point about declaring design apart from the implementation. This can provide a high level view of a BC or aggregate and its ubiquitous language. Not sure how the gain in abstraction would benefit my domain however, since my rules are pretty concrete and literal. I more often found myself needing abstraction in peripheral plumbing code e.g. command handling, event management, etc.

Comment: Regarding microservices, he also said that the granularity would probably be more like multiple microservices in one BC. Anyway, I don't do microservices ;)